# Torus topological space

Tags: general-topology

How can a topological space represent a torus? I mean from the definition of a topological space as a set of open subsets of a set. I can't intuitively see how it could represent it. Is it possible to write it down simply?

Comment: Put it in $\mathbb R^3$ and give it the subspace topology.

Comment: You're confusing a topological space and a topology. The latter is a collection $\tau$ of open subsets of a set $X$ satisfying certain conditions. The former is the set $X$ and a topology $\tau$ on $X$ (often denoted by the pair $(X,\tau)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the best way is to fix some embedding into $\mathbb R^3$ and take the subspace topology, as Grumpy Parsnip has said in the comments.

As another method, we have the usual topology on $\mathbb R^2$ given by the Euclidean metric.  Define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R^2$ by saying that $(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2)$ if $x_1-x_2\in\mathbb Z$ and $y_1-y_2\in\mathbb Z$.  Then the quotient space $\mathbb R^2/\sim$ (with the quotient topology) is homeomorphic to a torus.

Alternatively, let $\mathbb R^2/\sim$ be the set of equivalence classes of the relation $\sim$.  We define a metric on $\mathbb R^2/\sim$ by:

$$
\rho\left([(x_1,y_1)],[(x_2,y_2)]\right)=\inf\left\{\;\sqrt{(x_1-x_2+m)^2+(y_1-y_2+n)^2}\;\colon\;m,n\in\mathbb Z\;\right\}
$$

This is a particularly simple case of the *quotient metric* (for less nice equivalence relations, the definition is more complicated).  The topological space induced from this metric is homeomorphic to the torus.

Comment: Which function would we be using the subspace topology on?

Comment: @Sekots What definition are you using for the torus?  One possible embedding of the torus $\mathbb R^2/(2\pi\mathbb Z)^2$ is the map $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto(\cos\theta(1-a\cos\phi),\sin\theta(1-a\cos\phi),a\sin\phi)$ for some $a\in(0,1)$.  The image of $\mathbb R^2$ under this function is a topological subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

One way of thinking of the two dimensional torus is as the product space $S^1\times S^1$ given the product topology. Here, $S^1$ represents the one dimensional sphere, and the product topology is generated by the basis $\{U\times V:U, V \text{ are open in }S^1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ like subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, now identify $(0,x) - (1,x)$  and $(x,0)-(x,1)$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$, at first without the identifications the square has the subspace topology, but now put the quotient topology, where the open sets are the preimage of the open sets of the square via the natural projection.

This is beatifull construction because if take a sheef of paper and identify of the same way like the square below you get a fisical torus.